# fireEvent.press not working (React Native Testing Library)

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-test-renderer, react-native-testing-library

I am writing unit tests for my React Native project. My main screen is WelcomScreen.js and inside it is following custom button created using TouchableOpacity:

```
<TouchableOpacity
              testID={'selectEngButton'}
              activeOpacity={0.4}
              onPress={() => onSelectLanguage('en')}>
              <View
                // source={require('../../assets/images/ellipse.png')}
                style={Styles.selectorView}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../../assets/images/us.png')}
                  style={Styles.flagImage}
                />
              </View>
              <Image
                source={
                  activeLanguage === 'en'
                    ? darkMode
                      ? activelangdotdark
                      : activelangdot
                    : darkMode
                    ? inactivelangdotdark
                    : inactivelangdot
                }
                style={Styles.activityDot}
              />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Following is method called onPress event:

```
const onSelectLanguage = (lang) => {
    setActiveLanguage(lang);
    i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
    saveData(APP_LANG, lang);
};
```

Following is test for it:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {act, create} from 'react-test-renderer';
import ConfigureStore from '../src/redux/store';
import WelcomeScreen from '../src/screens/auth/WelcomeScreen';
import {ThemeContextProvider} from '../src/themes/themeProvider';
import {fireEvent, render} from '@testing-library/react-native';

const store = ConfigureStore();

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('Welcom Screen tests', () => {
  const navigation = {
    navigate: jest.fn(),
  };

  const onSelectLanguage = jest.fn();

  it('select english language', () => {
    const {getByTestId} = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ThemeContextProvider>
          <WelcomeScreen navigation={navigation} />
        </ThemeContextProvider>
      </Provider>,
    );

    const button = getByTestId('selectEngButton');

    console.log('btn002', button);

    fireEvent.press(button);

    expect(onSelectLanguage).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But it gives me following error:

```
 Welcome Screen tests › select english language

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      45 |     fireEvent.press(button);
      46 |
    > 47 |     expect(onSelectLanguage).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                              ^
      48 |   });
      49 | });
      50 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/WelcomeScreen-test.js:47:30)
```

I'm following official guide and doing exactly same things. But it doesn't fire onPress event on the component. What I'm doing wrong with it?

Comment: How exactly is the onSelectLanguage mock function related to the code under test? It only appears on two lines, one where you define it and another where you expect it to have been called - what could have called it?

Comment: When I'm testing a button, so what do you expect that where it should be placed?

Comment: The approach you're using would be appropriate where the event callback is a _prop_, but it's unclear whether that's the case here (you haven't provided a [mre]) and you'd have to actually _pass the mock function as a prop_. If `onSelectLanguage` is defined inside the component, you shouldn't be mocking it (and in a function-based component _can't_).